# Strange problem with dynamic cast C++

Tags: c++

I'm just new to C++, and doing a small project which implementing some inheritance. It can basically be summarized below:

```
//.h file
class Food{
public:
 Food();
 virtual ~Food();
};

class Animal{
public:
 Animal();
 virtual ~Animal();
 virtual void eat( Food f);
};

class Meat : public Food{
public:
 Meat();
 ~Meat();
};

class Vegetable : public Food{
public:
 Vegetable();
 ~Vegetable();
};

class Carnivore : public Animal{
public:
 Carnivore();
 ~Carnivore();
 void eat(Food f);
};

//.cpp file

Food::Food()
{
do something;
}

Food:~Food()
{
do something;
}

Animal::Animal()
{
do something;
}

Animal::~Animal()
{
do something;
}

Meat::Meat()
{
do something;
}

Meat::~Meat()
{
do something;
}

Vegetable::Vegetable()
{
do something;
}

Vegetable::~Vegetable()
{
do something;
}

Carnivore::Carnivore()
{
do something;
}

Carnivore::~Carnivore()
{
do something;
}

void Carnivore::eat(Food f)
{
 Meat* m = dynamic_cast<Meat*>(&f); 
 if(m != 0) cout << "can eat\n";
 else cout << "can not eat\n";
}

//main.cpp

int main()
{
Animal* a;
Food* f;

Meat m;
Vegetable v;
Carnivore c;

a = &c;
f = &v;
a->eat(*f);
f = &m;
a->eat(*f);


return 1;
}
```

And the output:

```
can not eat
can not eat
```

Comment: @Tomalak -1: okay, the problem isn't clearly stated, but it is clear if you read the code.

Comment: @Autopulated: I agree, which is why you'll find a well-written answer by me listed below.

Comment: @Tuan: I am glad to see someone using polymorphism without dynamic allocation!

Comment: @Matthieu: Ooh yes, nice isn't it!?

Comment: How is this "not a real question"? Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have a function like this:

```
void Carnivore::eat(Food f)
```

it takes its parameter *by value*. That means a copy of the provided object is made.

In this case, you're specifying a type `Food`, so you end up with a `Food` object. No magic polymorphism, nothing. Just a bog-standard `Food` object.

This is known as *slicing*; please go ahead and look up this term, as there is loads of stuff about it on the web.

In short, though, you can maintain the use of polymorphism by accepting a reference to the existing polymorphic object:

```
void Carnivore::eat(Food& f)
```

Also, next time please post a minimal testcase. That's a *huge* snippet of code!

Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing food by value into the eating function. For polymorphism to work you need to pass either by reference or by pointer:

(by pointer:)

```
void Carnivore::eat(Food* f)
{
 Meat* m = dynamic_cast<Meat*>(f); 
 if(m != 0) cout << "can eat\n";
 else cout << "can not eat\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what's known as the "slicing problem". Your functions are taking a *copy* of the object you pass. The copy is being generated by the copy constructor for the base type, and any specialization you've done for the derived class is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Object slicing is what causing the problem in your implementation.

Your `eat()`  function should take either *reference* to `Food` or *pointer* to `Food` as explained below:

```
virtual void eat(Food & f);

//usage
Meat meat;
animal.eat(meat);
```

Or

```
virtual void eat(Food * pf);

//usage
Meat meat;
animal.eat(&meat); //note &
```

Comment: That's not really an explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

C++'s run-time polymorphism (aka virtual function calls / virtual dispatch) requires that the functions be called via a pointer or reference to a base class.  Here, your eat function takes a Food argument **by value**... which copies or *slices* the part of the *f value and creates a new `Food` object.  Such objects can never be casted by `dynamic_cast<Meat*>`, because the `Meat` part has been chopped off.  Just change to `Carnivore::eat(const Food& f)` and it will work....